# The transfer not showing on blockchain

Tags: tokens, erc-20

For this contract, there is a 0.1% "fees" on the transfer. I amended the ERC20 transfer function as follow;

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    uint256 fees = (1*_value)/1000;
    _value -= fees;
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    _transfer(msg.sender, 0x7261fc332463f4f211ee316d14bb22fb5f37ebb3, fees);
 }
```

The function works fine, by checking the wallet.

However the 0.1% transaction do not show up on any block. Is there a way to make it show up on etherscan.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the token transfer your contract needs to emit a `Transfer` event. Event should be in following format:

```
Transfer(address from_address, address to_address, uint256 value)
```